# How to pivot up data by summing values?

Tags: sas

I have a data set as below. I need to print 2 data sets -one for EU and other for US such that I have unique IDs in the rows and the sales for each ID is the sum of the sales.( E.g. for ID 1 sales will be 1200+1500, for ID 4 sales will be 3000+9000). Can someone please suggest some proc or short way of getting this?

```
     ID Country Sales
     1  EU      1200
     2  US      1000
     1  EU      1500
     3  EU      2000
     4  US      3000
     4  US      9000
```

Comment: Is it possible for an ID to be in the data with Country='EU' for one record and Country='US' for another record?

Comment: Do you want to separate total sales per country as well as per id? If so I will edit my answer.

Comment: yes, each country data should have unique IDs but 1 ID can be present in more than 1 countries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be easy with a proc sql containing a group by statement:

```
  proc sql;
  create table work.sales_by_id as (
    select ID, country, sum( sales ) as total_sales
    from input_data
    group by ID, country 
  ) 
  quit;
```

Edit: added grouping by country as I think this is what you wanted